# How can I automatically apply model filters to GET requests in Sails

Tags: sails.js

I want all all the HTTP GET requests to the API generated by Sails to be restricted. So how can I apply a filter to all incoming API GET requests.

More specifically, most of my models have an attribute called `publicityLevel`. This tells whether a model is public or not. So I want all my models to automatically apply a filter (like `publicityLevel: 'public'`) for all incoming GET requests.

Even more advanced, I'd like to write some code which decides whether the user can see a specific model or not. So if a user is an admin, don't apply this filter. If the user isn't an admin, apply this filter.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem to solve with blueprints and I solved it.

**If we are talking about BLUEPRINTS:**

You can get `modelName` from `req.options.model` when you are using Blueprints.
I was using it to check if user belongs to the same group as element.

Unfortunately you can't use `this[modelName]` as option is giving you model name starting with small letter, so first you have to upper case first letter with e.g.  `var modelName = req.options.model.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + req.options.model.slice(1);`

and then you are free to use `this[modelName].whateverYouNeed`

I used it for generic policy to let user editing only his own group elements.

```
var modelName = req.options.model.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + req.options.model.slice(1)
  var elementID = null

  if (req.params.id) { // To handle DELETE, PUT
    elementID = req.params.id
  }
  if (req.body.id) { // To handle POST
    elementID = req.body.id
  }

  this[modelName].findOne({
    id: elementID
  }).exec(function(err, contextElement) {
    if(err) {
      return res.serverError(err)
    }
    if(contextElement.group=== req.user.group.id) {
      sails.log('accessing own: ' + modelName)
      return next()
    }
    else {
      return res.forbidden('Tried to access not owned object')
    }
  })
```

Comment: oh. Sorry! This is POLICY.